# dragula imported but not working. Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

In my project for drag and drop I'm using dragula package. The problem is when I'm using the cdn then its run properly but using laravel webpack.mix technique I importe dragula using npm then it is not working can anyone tell me what I did wrong.

## resources/js/dragula.js

```
import dragula from 'dragula';
```

## webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/dragula.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/sweetalert.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/dragula.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

## blade file

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/dragula.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/sweetalert.js') }}"></script>
```

In console it return error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dragula is not defined
    at window.onload (dashboard:451)
```

Comment: `import dragula from 'dragula';
window.dragula = dragula;` try this

Answer (score 0):

## solved

**resources/js/dragula.js**

```
import dragula from 'dragula';
window.dragula = dragula;
```